# creating an rpm package that updates a previous version

Tags: linux, rpmbuild

I have an existing rpm software-1.0.0-x86_64.rpm
I would like to create a new rpm package that:
(a) only replaces a few files if the previous package is already installed
(b) does a complete install of all files if the previous package is not installed

The reason I want this behavior is because if the previous package has already been installed, then i don't want to overwrite changes that the running software has made and instead i want to update just a few binaries.

Is this a reasonable thing to ask an rpm package to do? If so, how to achieve it?

Comment: Yes rpm packages do that. It would behoove to take some time a check out http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/index.html :)

Comment: you're saying read through the zillion pages of rpm "howto" that I started reading today and then got bored? ;-)

Comment: This link is better: http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/index.html

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks

Comment: This maybe of intrest also http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Dnf :) enjoy your jouney into rpm's

Comment: @RedCricket and if you could give me an idea of what I should be doing, like which parts of the spec file, which directives are relevant to this, that would be great

Comment: It is important to be clear about what is meant by "this". You probably need to see this documentation: http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-rpm-build.html "Chapter 11. Building Packages: A Simple Example"

Comment: consider tagging some of your files as "config" files

Comment: and if you do so; take look here for noreplace etc... http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/~jw35/docs/rpm_config.html

Comment: "i don't want to overwrite changes that the running software has made and instead i want to update just a few binaries." you might need to break things out into separate RPM's them. Maybe something like software-config1.0.0-x86_64.rpm for your configs and software-1.0.0-x86_64.rpm for your binaries.